# Excel VBA filtering a column and then copying each item in the area collection to a matching row

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy-paste

I have the following Excel Table:

```
 Create Date          Last Active Date        Age
 4/12/2017 5:54         4/17/2020 8:54      5 Days
                        4/19/2017 7:43       #N/A
                        4/12/2017 20:43      #N/A
 4/1/2017 23:20         4/3/2017 6:54       10 Days
                        4/15/2017 22:20      #N/A
```

What I want to do is to filter the Age Column by #N/A, and then copy each Last Active Date value to the same row in Create Date.  Seems easy enough, but I keep running into issues.  I am using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) property to then do a for each on each Area in there(non-contiguous rows), but when I go to copy the rows, it either copies the rows starting at Row 1 of the Create Date column, meaning the values get all out of whack OR it throws an error saying the ranges don't match.  Here is the code I have so far that I pulled from another page that talked about how to do this, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "#N/A"
    Dim lngrow As Long
    Dim FinalDest As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    lngrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set FinalDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C" & lngrow)
    Range("F2:F" & lngrow).Select

    For Each Rng In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        Set FinalDest = FinalDest.Offset(Rng.Rows.Count)
        Rng.Copy Destination:=FinalDest
    Next Rng
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

How can I accomplish this?  I want to filter it by #N/A, and then for each filtered row that remains, copy the value in Last Active Date to Create Date, (which will always be blank for these rows) and make sure they get copied to the proper rows, ie if Row 3 is the first filtered row, the value gets copied to rows 3 instead of row 2.

Comment: Hmm...thinking outside the box---could I not simply sort the rows by #N/A, then filter it by #N/A to get a continuous range and then do a simple copy and paste to avoid a lot of extra work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to filter your table. You have two feasible solutions:

**Solution 1 (without VBA):**
Assuming that Create Date is at A1:

-Insert a new column between Create Date and Last Active Date.

-Insert this function to B2--> =IF(A2="",IFNA(D2,C2),A2)

-Copy paste B2 till end of your column

-Copy all B column and paste them as values.

-Delete Column A

**Solution 2 (with VBA):**

You can loop through each row and check if the Age cell is #N/A, if true(#N/A), then you do the copy/paste from Last Active Date cell to Create Date Cell.

Solution 1 is much faster and easy. If you are interested in VBA solution let us know.

**Edit:** You can always change the following code for different conditions but since you said --> Create date value (which will always be blank for these rows):

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I believe the method I posted in the comment is a valid one also(it works doing it by hand, at least, so I'd assume it should give the same results in code) ...it needs to be VBA because the data is going to change each day so I want to be able to click a button and make that happen...

Comment: I missed your comment while posting the answer, still you don't need to filter or sort anything. If it is a daily operation please see my edit for vba solution.

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to simply sort the rows first by #N/A to limit the number of rows than looping through all of them?  I could set up a Do While Loop where the .value = "#N/A" and then set the value2 equal to each other. Once it reaches the last #N/A row the loop ends

Comment: It depends on how many #N/A values you have. Out of curiosity I compared two methods for 1000000 rows. I tested them assuming 2/3 of your data is #N/A. These timings may change a little bit each time you run the code but they will be about the same. My method took 14.07031 secs. Then I sorted them which took 1.832031 secs and then copied for the first 666667 cells and it took 12.21094 secs which makes a total of 14.04297 secs. I'd like to remind you that I already have known 666667 rows need to be changed, in your case you need to find out how many rows are #N/a which will result in more time.

Comment: Try it by sorting the Range and then setting Range.Value2 = Range.Value2...it should be a lot faster than copy and paste I would imagine, at least it has been in my experience

Comment: Well @MattE, I'm not planning to try what you want me to try because if you pay attention, what I do is not copy/pasting values.`Cells(i, 1)=Cells(i, 2)` is the same thing with `Range1.Value=Range2.Value`. What I tried to show you was just out of curiosity. Above code takes 14 secs to loop within 1 million rows without a need to sort. Do you have more than 1 million rows?Do you really need a time efficient code to run it once a day?So, have any of my solutions met your expectations?If so, you can accept this as an answer and ask "How to improve this working code" as a different question.Thanks